# Functioning humanoid society with negligible gravity

Tags: science-based, gravity, space-colonization, survival, humanoid

In a fictional world, a humanoid species settles upon a foreign planet and intends to build a colony on this planet with an eventual goal of full habitation. They originally chose this planet for settlement because it has water, fertile soil, and oxygen, elements needed for the species to survive as well as many precious metals and ores that can be mined. However, the planet has one major problem: a lack of gravity -- more specifically .1g. (Or 1/10 of the gravity the species is used to and needs based on its homeworld.) Luckily this species is technologically advanced, and has different types of robots and machines to help them navigate this new world. They cannot, however, figure out a way to make a gravitational field or a machine which serves this purpose.

The planet rotates around a sun similar to Earth's. The geography of the planet also includes temperate temperatures, several rivers, forests, and deserts. Weather includes regular rainy seasons, ~13 hours of sunlight a day, and occasional droughts. The planet has a large disposal of natural ores and gems under the surface. (The species has enough knowledge to access these.)

Once the original settlement is built on this planet, is there a way for this species to thrive for an extended period of time without sufficient gravity on this planet given the resources at their disposal?

Comment: Have you read The Integral Trees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Integral_Trees or Falling Free https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_Free  Both excellent examples of stories with societies living in low-to-zero G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your colonizers can build their homes in centrifuges, which need not be rapid if big enough.

If leaving the centrifuges makes them sick, they can use waldos (or other remote-controlled robots) to work in the field.

Perhaps I do not understand the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, for some reason, this slipped my mind.

Answer (score 0):

**They thrive.  And also suffer.**

[image: sunburned redhead]

[source](https://www.memesmonkey.com/topic/ginger+sunburn)

White people have skin evolved to deal with northern Europe.  White people have left northern Europe and have done very well in much sunnier parts of the world.  They also suffer from the sun which their skin does not handle well.

Your heavy world people do thrive well in their low grav new home.  They also suffer and struggle in characteristic ways.  These struggles will add energy to your story.  Maybe they are too tall.  Maybe they suffer from high blood pressure.  Maybe their bones are weak.  You can find speculation on the trouble humans would have living in low gravity, and you can make up your own stuff.  Adversity and struggle gives energy to a story!

Answer (score 0):

"They cannot, however, figure out a way to make a gravitational field or a machine which serves this purpose." So you're telling me they can cross interstellar space but are too stupid to figure out carousels?

Use large parabolic bowls spinning at the right speed so the perceived gravity is perpendicular to the floor. Using superconductors for efficient magnetic bearings allows you quite large carousels.

The same idea would be used if they choose to not inhabit the planet at all. They set up mining operations, nature preserves and launch infrastructure (mass-drivers, tethered rings, orbital rings, dynamically suspended space bridges or skyhooks). And life in orbital habitats using rotation to generate gravity.

The second approach seems much wiser anyways, because, by crossing interstellar space, they already demonstrated the ability to life in space for a long time and the gravity of the planet won't allow it to hold on to air or water in the inner system. That is unless we are discussing an outer solar system world like Pluto or Titan here.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably the [O'Neill cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder). Or, better still, arrays of them. If you found a suitable, relatively small asteroid that could be mined for materials without the huge cost of raising it against gravity, then it should be possible to create a habitat that could support more people than Earth.